# Projecting data from $S^n$ to $S^2$

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction, visualization

I have few points in $S^n$, i.e., the $n$-dimensional unit sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and I would like to project them down to $S^2$, i.e., the 2-dimensional unit sphere (embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$) to visualize it with the constraint that neighboring points should be close by. I spent some time playing with t-sne but of course, the points no longer lie on $S^2$. I normalized the projections but that introduces weird distortions, for instance, if the variance of one dataset is very small in $S^n$ as compared to other, I expect the same to hold in their $S^2$ projections; that is not the case upon normalizing t-sne. Any ideas? I would really like something that makes the previous statement hold.

Comment: Sounds like you have some code, data and visualizations already. Can you share some of them? It would be easier to help then.

Comment: How about [Dimensionality Reduction with Spherical Constraints](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~suresh/6160/spring09/projects/final/arvind.pdf) or [Spherical Laplacian Information Maps for dimensionality reduction](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~hero/Preprints/carter_ssp09.pdf)?

Comment: @Emre The first one looks interesting, I think I will just code up t-sne with the norm constraint and geodesic distance..

Comment: @Pratik, what was the disposition of your investigation of dimensionality reduction with spherical constraints?  Can you now answer your own question based on Emre's suggestions?  It would be great if you could post an update since this is a pretty fascinating question.

Answer (score 1):

I would view my points as elements of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and use [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) to project my points to $\mathbb{R}^3$ and then scale them to $S^2$.